# Problem with SplitViewController

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a problem with the splitviewcontroller. 
I have the code below and when i run the app, and pressing the rootviewcontroller, which is a table, the next view appeared in the rootviewcontroller part but not the detailview. 
May I know which part of code i did wrong?

Many Thanks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell
    Travel_Packer_HDAppDelegate *appDelegate = (Travel_Packer_HDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Animal *animal = (Animal *)[appDelegate.animals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setText:animal.name];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller
    Travel_Packer_HDAppDelegate *appDelegate = (Travel_Packer_HDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Animal *animal = (Animal *)[appDelegate.animals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(self.animalView == nil) {
        DetailViewController *viewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
        self.animalView = viewController;
        [viewController release];
    }

    // Setup the animation
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.animalView animated:YES];
    // Set the title of the view to the animal's name
    self.animalView.title = [animal name];
    // Set the description field to the animals description
    [self.animalView.animalDesciption setText:[animal description]];
    // Load the animals image into a NSData boject and then assign it to the UIImageView
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[animal imageURL]]];
    UIImage *animalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData cache:YES];
    self.animalView.animalImage.image = animalImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you have navigation controllers in each pane of split view controller? 
Then probably the issue in next line:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.animalView animated:YES];
```

due to you've just pushed the animalView to left navigation controller but you need right (detail pane) one.